# Python youtube api status.rejectionReason

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've looked through the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos
 But am unsure how to access status.rejectionReason with python.  I've been using youtube-uploader for my uploading, and I dont believe there is any commands to return the reason a video was rejected.  The ideal scenario would be to get a list of all my videos, check which ones have been rejected, then return the links of the ones that have been rejected.

Comment: Unless you add the code you tried, the effect it had, the effect it should have had and what went wrong this will be down- and closevoted fast. We do not write code for you,we help fix _your code_ ... see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have a (one) specific questions (per question asked) provide 
your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the `rejectionReason` is within a JSON "videos resource" format. You can access this with Python's built-in JSON library:

```
from json import load

with open('video.json') as file:  # Opens the JSON file and assigns it to the variable 'file' within the loop
    data = load(f)  # Loads the file into a dictionary which you can access with key:value pairs
```

The JSON file provided as a sample on the site follows this format for the rejectionReason:

```
"status": {
    "uploadStatus": string,
    "failureReason": string,
    "rejectionReason": string,
    "privacyStatus": string,
    "publishAt": datetime,
    "license": string,
    "embeddable": boolean,
    "publicStatsViewable": boolean
  }
```

So your final script would look like this I believe:

```
from json import *


def get_rejection_reason(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        data = load(f)

    return data["status"]["rejectionReason"]

get_rejection_reason("video.json")
```